# How to create multiple spreadsheets with a given name from a template

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have a web application developed in Google Apps Script and I need to have a sheet for each user where I can have user information and this can be consulted from the app. So I needed a sheet with the name of each user, but each sheet needed to have a certain format, a certain template. So I needed a function to help me automate the process because there are approximately 300 users and doing it manually is very tiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. A variable is created with the sheet that will serve as a template previously created as needed. Then I take the data from the names that I have listed on a sheet. Finally the array is traversed by duplicating the template and changing the user's name.

```
function duplicateTemplate() {
  let template = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('template')
  let users = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('users').getRange("A2:A").getDisplayValues().flat() // To convert matriz to array

  users .forEach(user => {
    template.getRange("A1").activate()
    let nueva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet()
    nueva.setName(user)
  })
};
```

The result is all your usernames each one in his own sheet

Comment: use of the type of range `getRange("A2:A"` often results in null values at the end of the array.  Which need to be filtered out.  I would recommend using the `Sheet.getRange(row,column,numrows,numcols)` to avoid that problem.  In your cause you could also use filter(e => e); however that runs the rish of removing data rows that may exist in your datarange.

Comment: Yes, what you say it is correct. 

`let users = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('users').getRange(2, 1, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getLastRow(), 1).getDisplayValues().flat()`